# Unpacking Dictionaries within a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Pandas Data Frame that contains a series of dictionaries, as follows:

```
df.head()

Index                 params                    score            
0   {'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'}    0.550
1   {'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'distance'}   0.550
2   {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'uniform'}    0.575
3   {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'distance'}   0.550
4   {'n_neighbors': 3, 'weights': 'uniform'}    0.575
```

The aim is to create a data frame with "n_neighbors" and "weights" as attributes for each instance and remove the `params` column. I achieved this by creating empty numpy arrays, looping and appending:

```
n_neighbors = np.array([])
weights = np.array([])

count = sum(df["score"].value_counts())

for x in range(count):
     n_neighbors = np.append(n_neighbors, df["params"][x]["n_neighbors"])

for x in range(count):
     weights = np.append(weights, df["params"][x]["weights"])

df["n_neighbors"] = n_neighbors
df["weights"] = weights
df = df.drop(["params"], axis=1)
```

This feels dirty and inefficient. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new dataframe from `df['params']` and join it to your original dataframe. As a convenience, [`pd.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) simultaneously returns a series and drops it from your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0, 1],
                   'params': [{'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'},
                              {'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'distance'}],
                   'score': [0.550, 0.550]})

res = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('params').tolist()))

print(res)

   Index  score  n_neighbors   weights
0      0   0.55            1   uniform
1      1   0.55            1  distance
```

Comment: Wonderful! There's quite clearly a gap in my knowledge here. What resources would you recommend to help me fix this? As it stands I don't think I'd ever be able to find you solution on my own...

Comment: The official [Pandas cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html) is a good starting point. And, of course, SO.

Answer (score 0):

easy

```
datapoints = list(dataframe['params'])
data = pd.DataFrame(datapoints)
data['score'] = list(dataframe['score'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score -1):

in your case , you don't need numpy. Normal python list feels better.   I remind you that a df is in fact a list of dictionary  ( each row a dict that are similar in  the list.  check Doku  ex : d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]} .  So follow the pattern. 
When your have it pass it  to the constructor  pd.DataFrame()

I guess the proper way to do .